# Conda package register file extensions in windows registry

Tags: python, registry, conda

I have a python package for an application that can open images. Packaging with conda already allows to create Start Menu entries for the entry points.

Now I want to register the file extensions that my application can open in the windows registry, so that the user can right click on a file and open it with my application. Is there a way this can be included in the installation of a conda package? And in an ideal case for the deinstallation, too.

If not, my solution would be to ask the user to execute a script file that does the registration instead, which is not the most elegant way.

Comment: You can use a `post-link` and `pre-unlink` script, see here: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/build-packages/link-scripts.html However, this does not give the user the option to choose whether they want the registration to happen, which I would consider a bad practice, so I would not recommend doing that. See also the warning at the bottom that these should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, this was basically what I was looking for, but I also understand your objections that it is probably not a good idea to implement it that way.

Comment: That's good to hear! In general, its a good question though :-)